# Add/remove slashes with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have the following scenario: If a user type something like

- http://domain.tld/category-a///// or
- http://domain.tld/category-a (without slash at the end)

he/she must be redirected to the original URL

- http://domain.tld/category-a/

How can this be achieved with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^category-([^/]*)//([^/]*)$ ./category-$1/ [R, L]
RewriteRule ^category-([^/]*)$ ./category-$1/ [R, L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For eg: If you want to redirect

```
From : http://www.project.com/myfolder/rss.php
To   : http://www.project.com/rss.php
```

then you should write this to your .htacess file

```
Redirect /myfolder/rss.php http://www.project.com/rss.php
```